# AVX512 Vector Multiplication Speed

Tags: c++, avx, avx2, avx512

I have Function like this:

```
#define SPLIT(zmm, ymmA, ymmB) \
ymmA = _mm512_castsi512_si256(zmm); \
ymmB = _mm512_extracti32x8_epi32(zmm, 1)

#define PAIR_AND_BLEND(src1, src2, dst1, dst2) \
dst1 = _mm256_blend_epi32(src1, src2, 0b11110000); \
dst2 = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(src1, src2, 0b00100001);

#define OPERATE_ROW_2(i, ymmA, ymmB)        \
zmm##i = _mm512_maddubs_epi16(zmm30, zmm##i);     \
zmm##i = _mm512_madd_epi16(zmm##i, zmm31);        \
SPLIT(zmm##i, ymmA, ymmB);

/*
 * multiply query to each code in codes.
 * @param n: number of codes
 * @param query: 64 x uint8_t array data
 * @param codes: 64 x n x uint8_t array data
 * @param output: n x int32_t array data, to store output data.
 */
void avx_IP_distance_64_2(size_t n,
                          const uint8_t *query,
                          const uint8_t *codes,
                          int32_t *output){
    __m512i zmm0, zmm1, zmm2, zmm3,
            zmm4, zmm5, zmm6, zmm7,
            zmm8, zmm9, zmm10, zmm11,
            zmm12, zmm13, zmm14, zmm15,
            zmm16, zmm17, zmm18, zmm19,
            zmm20, zmm21, zmm22, zmm23,
            zmm24, zmm25, zmm26, zmm27,
            zmm28, zmm29, zmm30, zmm31;

    __m256i ymm0, ymm1, ymm2, ymm3,
            ymm4, ymm5, ymm6, ymm7,
            ymm8, ymm9, ymm10, ymm11,
            ymm12, ymm13, ymm14, ymm15;

    zmm30 = _mm512_loadu_si512(query);
    zmm31 = _mm512_set1_epi16(1);

    int k_8 = n / 8;
    int left = n % 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < k_8; ++i){
        zmm0 = _mm512_loadu_si512(codes);
        zmm1 = _mm512_loadu_si512(codes + 64 * 1);
        zmm2 = _mm512_loadu_si512(codes + 64 * 2);
        zmm3 = _mm512_loadu_si512(codes + 64 * 3);
        zmm4 = _mm512_loadu_si512(codes + 64 * 4);
        zmm5 = _mm512_loadu_si512(codes + 64 * 5);
        zmm6 = _mm512_loadu_si512(codes + 64 * 6);
        zmm7 = _mm512_loadu_si512(codes + 64 * 7);

        OPERATE_ROW_2(0, ymm0, ymm1);
        OPERATE_ROW_2(1, ymm2, ymm3);
        OPERATE_ROW_2(2, ymm4, ymm5);
        OPERATE_ROW_2(3, ymm6, ymm7);
        OPERATE_ROW_2(4, ymm8, ymm9);
        OPERATE_ROW_2(5, ymm10, ymm11);
        OPERATE_ROW_2(6, ymm12, ymm13);
        OPERATE_ROW_2(7, ymm14, ymm15);

        ymm0 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm0, ymm1);
        ymm2 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm2, ymm3);
        ymm4 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm4, ymm5);
        ymm6 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm6, ymm7);
        ymm8 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm8, ymm9);
        ymm10 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm10, ymm11);
        ymm12 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm12, ymm13);
        ymm14 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm14, ymm15);

        PAIR_AND_BLEND(ymm0, ymm8, ymm1, ymm9);
        PAIR_AND_BLEND(ymm2, ymm10, ymm3, ymm11);
        PAIR_AND_BLEND(ymm4, ymm12, ymm5, ymm13);
        PAIR_AND_BLEND(ymm6, ymm14, ymm7, ymm15);

        ymm1 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm1, ymm9);
        ymm3 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm3, ymm11);
        ymm5 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm5, ymm13);
        ymm7 = _mm256_add_epi32(ymm7, ymm15);

        ymm1 = _mm256_hadd_epi32(ymm1, ymm3);
        ymm5 = _mm256_hadd_epi32(ymm5, ymm7);

        ymm1 = _mm256_hadd_epi32(ymm1, ymm5);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i *)(output), ymm1);

        codes += 8 * 64;
        output += 8;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < left; ++i){
        OPERATE_ROW_1(0);
    }
}


#define LOOP 10

int main(){
    int d = 64; 
    int q = 1;
    int n = 100000;

    std::mt19937 rng;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> distrib;

    uint8_t *codes = new uint8_t[d * n]; 
    uint8_t *query = new uint8_t[d * q]; 

    int32_t *output = new int32_t[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j){
            // codes[d*i+j] = j;
            codes[d * i + j] = int(distrib(rng)) * 127;
        }   
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j){
            // query[d*i+j] = j;
            query[d * i + j] = int(distrib(rng)) * 127 - 64; 
        }   
    }

    Timer timer;
    timer.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; ++i){
        avx_IP_distance_64_2(n, query, codes, output);
    }
    timer.end("Second type");
    return 0;
}
```

When n = 10k, time duration is: 0.143917 ms

When n = 100k, time duration is: 3.2002 ms

When N is less than 10k, the time consumption basically increases linearly.

I suspect it’s a caching problem, but I’m not sure.

I want to know why the time consumption does not increase linearly with n?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please don't show text as images (they are not searchable/copyable/...). Also, I don't see a 20 times increase in your timings -- you may have more outliers. But you are also timing the concatenation of `"load " + s` and whatever overhead your `Timer` class may have.

Comment: @Sopel I have edit , post my code

Comment: @chtz sorry, I have edit my question, wish for your help

Comment: now it indeed looks like a cache size issue. You're processing 640kB in the first test, and 6.4MB in the second one. If you plot the execution times for varying `n` at, say, 2^k for k in 1..20 you will see that it's not linear and the jumps happen at sizes that correspond to sizes of cache levels. This is only visible because when calling avx_IP_distance_64_2 the data is already in the cache because it was just produced.

Comment: @Sopel thanks for your reply,  You mean the codes are already in the cache after assigning values to the codes? Is there room for optimization of this code?

Comment: Skylake-X / Cascade Lake has an L2 cache size of 1MiB.  Your larger size exceeds that.  See [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126311)

Comment: Are you sure `_mm512_maddubs_epi16` does what you want?  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddubsw treats its second operand as signed (`int8_t`), but both of your inputs are declared `uint8_t`.  Also, if possible, cache-block your code so you generate a chunk (comfortably smaller than 1MiB) and process it, then go back and do the next chunk through each step of processing.

Comment: Can you keep 512-bit vectors for another step or 2?  Perhaps with [`vpermt2d`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermt2w:vpermt2d:vpermt2q:vpermt2ps:vpermt2pd) aka `_mm512_permutex2var_epi32` which SKX can run as a single uop, to prep inputs for `_mm512_add_epi32`.  And perhaps the blend can be replaced with merge-masking at some point?  Note that `_mm256_hadd_epi32` costs 2 shuffles and 1 add; IDK if that can be avoided, I haven't really followed what's getting added to what.

Comment: Style note: declaring all of `zmm0 .. 31` is really ugly and pointless.  Give your variables meaningful names (or just something like code0, code1, etc.), and declare them as they're initialized.  Also, the YMM0 register is the low half of ZMM0, but that's not how your C variables work.  So that's another reason *not* to name your vars this way.  It's the opposite of helpful.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your reply~ I will ensure that the data range is between 0~127, so I don’t think there will be any problems with `_mm512_maddubs_epi16`.

Comment: @PeterCordes The code implements the inner product of a uint8 vector of length 64 and other uint8 of length 64. The fastest way I can find is to use `_mm256_hadd_epi32`. I don’t know if you have any better suggestions.

Comment: After the `_mm512_madd_epi16` step, it would be worth trying keeping 512-bit vector size for longer, although the 2x shuffle uops per `hadd` can quickly be a bottleneck on port 5, maybe as bad as you have now with 8x `_mm512_extracti32x8_epi32` plus shuffle and blend. e.g.  4x `_mm512_hadd_epi32` to reduce down to 4 vectors, then another 2x to reduce down to 2. Maybe then reduce them down to 256-bit each with one `PAIR_AND_BLEND` + add. Then 2x lane-crossing `vpermt2d` (`_mm512_permutex2var_epi32`) with vector constants to pick the right elements to set up for another add down to one `__m256i`

Comment: Yeah, I think 4x + 2x 512-bit hadd is same number of total shuffles as your initial SPLIT and PAIR_AND_BLEND steps, but without any of the blend uops, and with fewer adds.  And the result is only 2 vectors, with less work left to be done (not as bad as the 2x + 1x hadd you do at the end)